# How to use javadoc @argfiles from gradle javadoc task

Tags: gradle, javadoc

I need to use javadoc @argfile from a gradle javadoc task or from gradle.
For example:

```
task myJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
   source = sourceSets.server.allJava
   maxMemory = '512m'
   options.addStringOption("use")
   options.addStringOption("author")
   options.addStringOption("version")
   options.addStringOption("@" + "groupfile")
}
```

The last line doesn't work. The gradle version is 2.11

Answer (score 1):

One day later I have found the answer:

```
task myJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
   source = sourceSets.server.allJava
   maxMemory = '512m'
   options.addStringOption("use")
   options.addStringOption("author")
   options.addStringOption("version")
   options.optionFiles("groupfile")
}
```

The reference is in [Converting AntBuilder Javadoc to Javadoc Task](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Converting-AntBuilder-Javadoc-to-Javadoc-Task-td3425491.html). The Gradle reference is [Interface MinimalJavadocOptions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/external/javadoc/MinimalJavadocOptions.html). I saw it with the custom google search on the gradle website